# How to derive sales contribution in a log-log regression media mix model?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, lognormal-distribution, logarithm, marketing

I am working on a media mix model to determine how different media channels impact sales.
Since there is a non-linear relationship between sales and media spend, I needed to apply a log transformation on both the dependent variable and the independent variables.

The model is as follows (numbers are for illustration):

**ln(units sold)=4.40 + 0.05 × ln(spend on digital) + 0.4 × ln(spend on affiliate)**

I have consulted other resources and understand how to interpret the coefficient - in this example, a 1% increase in spend on digital leads to a 0.05% increase in units sold.

However, I also need to figure out in total how much each of the media channels contributes towards sales. For example, say for one particular week, if we sell 1000 units, I need to determine that display contributes about 30 units, affiliate contributes about 300 units.

Currently, I tried 2 approaches and am not sure if either one is correct - if anyone has experience working on log-log (multiplicative) media mix model and can provide inputs, that'd be much appreciated!

**Approach 1**

Digital contribution to units sold = **exponential [coefficient x ln (spend on digital)].**

For example, if that week, we **spend $1000 on digital**, contribution to units sold would be
**= exp [0.05 * ln(1000)] = 1.41 units.**

As you can see the contribution value is very very small and doesn't seem right.

**Approach 2**

**100% increase** in digital spend would lead to **5% (0.05 * 100)  increase in units sold**.

Therefore, if over a year, we **sell about 100K units and spend $1M in digital**, the sale contribution by digital would be **100k * 5% = 5K units**. The number seems more reasonable now but I don't know this approach is mathematically correct.

Comment: Since the effects are essentially multiplicative, you need to present a different way and you need to consider non-zero base amounts of spending.  So if you spend $\$1000$ on digital and $\$1000$ on affiliates and sell about $1823$ units, then you might say this is about $1.41$ times what you would have sold spending $\$1$ on digital and about $15.8$ times what you would have sold spending $\$1$ on affiliates.  If you instead spent $\$1000000$ on each you could multiply sales by another $1.41$ and $15.8$

Comment: thank you - when I tried this approach, the derived contribution seems really high. For example, if we spend 10K on affiliate and sell 16k units, based on this approach:  affiliate multiplier = exp [ 0.4 * ln(10,000) ] = 39.8 --> affiliate contributon = 16k - 16k/39.8 = 15.7k units. So affiliate contributes about 97% of all units sold, meaning if we don't spend on affiliate, we would have sold only about 3% of the units. That seems way too high.

Comment: It is your model, and it certainly suggests that spending $\$10000$ on affiliates rather than $\$1$ multiplies sales by $39.8$.  In what sense is that too high?  If you model was fitted over a smaller range of spending, then you could instead use a more realistic baseline:  for example spending $\$10000$ on affiliates rather than $\$5000$ multiplies sales by $1.3$ and you would attribute $24\%$ of sales to the higher spending on affiliates